# Putting images under header and paragraph

Tags: html, css

My mind has gone blank. I'm trying to put my images under the h3 and paragraph using `display: flex;` with space-between the 3 images but I'm stumped as to making it work.

I look forward to someone assisting me. Code below. Ignore all the `border:` added to css, I just put them in to sometimes help me know where everything is at.

Thanks Luke.

```css
.join {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    top: 37rem;
    background: rgb(18,28,38);
    height: 400px;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.join-wording h3{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.join-wording{
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 20px 0 0 10px;
}
.clickLink{
    color: cornflowerblue;
}

.join-image{
    border: 2px solid pink;
}

.join-image img{
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="join"> <!--rgb(18,28,38)-->
        <div class="join-wording">
            <h3>Meditaite with friends</h3>
            <p>Bring a friend along and you both get a free session. <a class="clickLink" href="/">Click here to register a friend</a>.</p>
        </div>
        <div class='join-image'>
            <img class="group" src="./images/dylan-gillis-YJdCZba0TYE-unsplash (1).jpg" alt="Group Yoga" width="300px">
            <br>
            <img class="group" src="./images/bruce-mars-gJtDg6WfMlQ-unsplash.jpg" alt="freinds yoga" width="300px">
            <br>
            <img class="group" src="./images/kaylee-garrett-GaprWyIw66o-unsplash.jpg" alt="beahc yoga" width="300px">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `flexbox` on almost every container to achieve what you want.

I changed:

```
.image-wrapper > img{
    height: 150px;
    width: auto;
}
```

to

```
.image-wrapper > img{
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```css
.join {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    top: 37rem;
    background: rgb(18,28,38);
    height: 400px;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.join-wording {
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 20px 20px 0 20px;
    min-height: 50px; /* min-height allows growth */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 1 80px;
}

.join-wording > h3{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.join-wording > p{
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.clickLink{
    color: cornflowerblue;
}

.join-image{
    margin: 20px 20px 0 20px;
    border: 2px solid pink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 1 1 auto; 
}

.image-wrapper{
  margin:auto;
}

.image-wrapper > img{
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="join"> <!--rgb(18,28,38)-->
      <div class="join-wording">
          <h3>Meditaite with friends</h3>
          <p>Bring a friend along and you both get a free session. <a class="clickLink" href="/">Click here to register a friend</a>.</p>
      </div>
      <div class='join-image'>
        <div class="image-wrapper">
            <img class="group" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/uw-s3-cdn/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2017/11/04133712/waterfall.jpg" alt="Group Yoga" width="300px">
        </div>
          <div class="image-wrapper">
            <img class="group" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/uw-s3-cdn/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2017/11/04133712/waterfall.jpg" alt="freinds yoga" width="300px">
        </div>
          <div class="image-wrapper">
            <img class="group" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/uw-s3-cdn/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2017/11/04133712/waterfall.jpg" alt="beahc yoga" width="300px">
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hey guys, 
it works perfect the only thing I'm not understanding is the 3rd image is falling outside of the width:100%; I'm struggling to understand why it's doing that.

Comment: that's because I set the height to a fixed 150px. Let me change it real quick

Comment: @LM17, its fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're going for, but to have the images inline under your header and paragraph, you want your `display: flex` on the parent container of the images:

```css
.join {
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(18,28,38);
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.join-wording h3{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.join-wording{
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 20px 10px;
}
.clickLink{
    color: cornflowerblue;
}

.join-image{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}

.join-image img{
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    /* calculates 1/3 of the space minus 2 times the border */
    width: calc(33.33% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="join"> <!--rgb(18,28,38)-->
      <div class="join-wording">
          <h3>Meditaite with friends</h3>
          <p>Bring a friend along and you both get a free session. <a class="clickLink" href="/">Click here to register a friend</a>.</p>
      </div>
      <div class='join-image'>
        <img class="group" src="https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1573556291531-a5d957d7e4e7?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTh8fHlvZ2ElMjBncm91cHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="beahc yoga">
          <img class="group" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1573462239448-06b5cde9df64?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MjJ8fHlvZ2ElMjBncm91cHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="Group Yoga">
          <img class="group" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554977932-040e7f5853b3?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTJ8fHlvZ2ElMjBncm91cHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="freinds yoga">      
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution of your question ps some advices to guide you : check the css I didn't change  anything  in the html because it's your own work .i just fix some things and now you can see the difference .and this should work the way you want :

```css
.join {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    top: 37rem;
    background: rgb(18,28,38);
    height: 900px;/* i change  this  to 900px because your images heigt is height than the width of the main div*/
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    align-items: center;
   justify-content: space-around;/* I add this two properties[align-items,justify-content]just to make your page more beautiful you can delet them if you want */
}
.join-wording h3{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.join-wording{
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 20px 20px 0 10px;
}
.clickLink {
    color: cornflowerblue;
}

.join-image{
    border: 2px solid pink;
}

.join-image img{
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 30px; /* your code didn't work because the margin bottom of the above div was 0px and the margin of images was only  5px*/
}
img {
    margin: 5px;/* add some spaces between each image*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="join"> <!--rgb(18,28,38)-->
        <div class="join-wording">
            <h3>Meditaite with friends</h3>
            <p>Bring a friend along and you both get a free session. <a class="clickLink" href="/">Click here to register a friend</a>.</p>
        </div>
        <div class='join-image'>
            <img class="group" src="Dr.jpg" alt="Group Yoga" width="300px">
            <br>
            <img class="group" src="Dr.jpg" alt="freinds yoga" width="300px">
            <br>
            <img class="group" src="Dr.jpg" alt="beahc yoga" width="300px">
        </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```